# MySQL Connection.State is 'undefined'

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, localhost, database-connection

I've been following along with this [Node.js, Express & MySQL full stack tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrj9AohVhPA&t=1670s) but the result of the connection request (a console log of connection.state) returns 'undefined' to the terminal rather than 'connected' as expected.

Can anyone please explain why this is, and why the connection state of 'undefined' doesn't seem to matter (as the fetch call to the db still successfully returns the required db table items)? What bearing (if any) do the client connection properties of Command:Sleep and State:None have on this returned 'undefined' Connection State?

The db is a windows instance of MySQL on a server machine in my home network (localhost:3306). The Express app is locally hosted on 5500 on a separate laptop in the same home network and is using mySQL2. I consequently changed the HOST in the .env file to the IP of the server machine in my network and ensured that the ports are open on both machines. The app has successfully fetched table data from the back-end. I'm just keen to understand the reason for the 'undefined' connection state.

I'm using the MySQL Workbench UI on the server machine and this shows in Client Connections that a connection was made from my dev laptop, however as above, the connection properties displayed in Workbench show that the 'Command' type is 'Sleep' and the 'State' is 'None'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but was able to fix it. Earlier in that tutorial, I did `npm install mysql2` instead of `npm install mysql`. So my `dbService.js` looked like:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
});

connection.connect((err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('db ' + connection.state);
    }
})
```

In order to fix, change the first line to:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
```